# can not find K-CoPMAN

Tags: ros, mapping, 3d-object-recognition, knowrobtutorials, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

1-) I can not find (K-CoPMAN) which refer to knowledge enable cognitive perception for manipulation, which is required for combination of perception and knowledge processing ?!
any help pleas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45792/can-not-find-k-copman/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Parts of the K-COPMAN system are contained in the prolog_perception package, but I am not sure if this still works under more recent ROS distributions. Similar functionality can be realized by writing an interface to a perception system of your choice (as described in the knowrob_tutorial package). The Prolog predicates in knowrob_perception may be useful for this.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1